# Use an inductive proof to show this proposition

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-writing, proof-explanation, solution-verification

I'm having trouble trying to show this proposition using an inductive proof. Please explain in as many details as you can so I can understand.
$$
\sum_{i=0}^h(i2^i) = ((h - 1) 2^h\cdot 2^1) + 2, h \ge 0
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If you explain where you got stuck in more detail, the contributors here will be more willing to help. (If you are going to add further details, please edit your post rather than posting them as a comment.)

Comment: Thanks for the welcome Joe, I'll make sure to do that

Comment: For next time, note that you can enclose entire expressions in dollar signs, not each term separately. It looks nicer, too.

Comment: The place to start is to manually examine the 4 cases of $h=0, h=1, h=2,$ and $h=3$ separately.  See if they are all true.  Then, using your work in these cases as a guide, assume it is true for $h=H$, and try to prove that it is therefore true for $h=(H+1)$.  See what you need to fill in that gap.  Then look for a pattern in your manual examination of the 4 cases to see if that helps.  If problem still unsolved, simply edit your query to *show* **all** of your work.

Answer (score 2):

Note this follows directly from the geometric series formula $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}x^i=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}$$

Then differentiating gives $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}ix^{i-1}=\frac{-(n+1)x^{n}(1-x)+(1-x^{n+1})}{(1-x)^2}=\frac{nx^{n+1}-(n+1)x^n+1}{(x-1)^2}$$

Thus $$\sum_{i=0}^{n}ix^{i}=\frac{nx^{n+2}-(n+1)x^{n+1}+x}{(x-1)^2}$$

and now set $x=2$ and simplify.

---

By induction.

Induction start:

For $h=0$ we have $\sum_{i=0}^{0}i2^{i}=0$ and $((0-1)2^{0+1})+2=-2+2=0.$

For  $h=1$ we have $\sum_{i=0}^{1}i2^{i}=2$ and $((1-1)2^{1+1})+2=2$.

Induction hypothesis:

Now assume it holds for $h=k$.

Induction step:

For every $k$, if the statement holds for $k$, then it also holds for $k+1$. Indeed we have $$\sum_{i=0}^{k+1}i2^{i}=\sum_{i=0}^{k}i2^{i}+(k+1)2^{k+1}$$
$$=((k-1)2^{k+1})+2+(k+1)2^{k+1}$$
$$=2^{k+1}\big[(k-1)+(k+1)\big]+2$$
$$=2^{k+1}\cdot2k+2$$
$$=((\color{red}{k+1}-1)2^{\color{red}{k+1}+1})+2.$$